# How to improve the cartographic design of graticules?

Tags: arcmap, cartography, arcgis-10.1, grids-graticules

The attached image shows a conflict between the graticule and the state boundary on a map.  I have not found a way to display user-defined lines of latitude, which would solve the 42 degree line conflict.

How can I resolve this conflict in Arcmap 10.1 by having better control of where the graticule parallels are placed?

[image]

Comment: It might be best to split your questions. Otherwise you run the risk of having answers that are both right and wrong at the same time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Data Frames Properties dialog, select Grids, then select your graticule and click Properties. The last tab (Intervals) in Properties allows you to modify the interval for your parallels and meridians, as well as their origin. In your example your merdians are every 4°, probably the same for the parallels. The default origin is -90, which with 4° intervals places a parallel at 42°. Change -90 to 43 and your graticule parallel will be drawn at 43°. These options are not available in the wizard you use to create the graticule in the first place.

(If this isn't what you mean by "resolve the conflict", try to be more precise about what you're looking for.)

Comment: I thought "resolve the conflict" meant to draw the parallel and the border using lines that can be visually differentiated. But it's just so much easier to draw the parallel somewhere else.

Comment: That solved my conflicting lines issue perfectly--thanks.

Answer (score 3):

ArcGIS has different methods for creating grids and graticules.  In the Data Frame properties, there is a [Grids and Graticules Wizard](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/A_quick_tour_of_data_frame_grids_and_the_Grids_and_Graticules_Wizard/00s90000000t000000/).  From the 10.1 help:

> They don't appear in data view. If you are interested in creating grid
>   or graticule features that draw in data view, you might want to look
>   into using grid and graticule layers.

The grid and graticule layers can be found in the [Grids and Graticules toolset](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/An_overview_of_the_Grids_and_Graticules_toolset/00700000002v000000/) in the Cartography toolset.  This will create a feature classes.

Using either of these tools, you should be able to modify the position of the lines of latitude/longitude to eliminate conflicts with state boundaries.  Or, you can change the style of the lines.